# How do i use jquery to find out which browser client is using

Tags: jquery

Based on that i can add CSS feature to one element of my page.
Can anybody please give an example?

Comment: http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).  However, this is highly discouraged, since it doesn't cope with new or rare browsers.  As the docs note:

> We recommend against using this
>   property; please try to use feature
>   detection instead (see
>   [`jQuery.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/)).

`$.browser` will be removed from future versions of jQuery.

If you give us more information, we may be able to suggest a better solution.

EDIT: As the docs say, you can use flags like `$.browser.webkit` (true for webkit) or `$.browser.ie`, and get the version from `$.browser.version`.

Comment: How do i will use $.browser to find out the browser type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery.browser or $.browser property.
Check this URL: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/